# How do I use R packages in an Anaconda environment that are not in the Anaconda r channel

Tags: r, anaconda

I want to use Anaconda to provide separate isolated environments, each with different combinations of r-packages. If this was Python, I would specify an environment .yml file with Python Anaconda packages where those exist, and pip-ones for those that are not in Anaconda.

For R, a similar situation exist, some R packages are not in Anaconda. If I do install.packages("package_name") the packages end up in my user homedir (on windows in Documents/R/win-library...). This is not ideal, because these installed packages are not confined within the Anaconda environment and can be seen from all Anaconda environments.

Two questions:

How can I specify these (non-Anaconda r-packages) in the environment .yml file, if possible?
How can I install non-Anaconda r-packages so they are confined within an Anaconda environment.

In summary, I want to achieve environent isolation for R in the same manner it is achived with Python.

Regards Niels Jespersen

Comment: Not anaconda, but I use renv to achieve that.

Comment: Well, I found out that install.packages("package_name") actually end up in a library specific to the current Anaconda environment, which is more than half way. I would prefer to specify all nedded packages in the environment .yml file though. This centralizes dependency management for the environment